# CKeditor Error - Unable to set property 'cssText' of undefined or null reference on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Browser - IE11 (Edge)
ckeditor v4.4.7 latest

CKeditor doesn't load, it gives a strange error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'cssText' of undefined or null reference
File: plugin.js, Line 296, Column: 4
```

Does anyone has way around this issue.
It works perfectly on other IE browsers.

Screenshot:
[image]

---

On click of the error line, following is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You have some 3rd party plugin (about which you didn't mention) installed AFAICS, so how are we supposed to tell what's wrong? Additionally, you didn't ask any question. Clearly, you should report this bug to the plugin's author.

Comment: Yes just found the root issue, Was using the imagepaste plugin wherein the code written for cssText was written wrong for IE browsers. Now fixed in new release.